# asp.net core razor and ajax: is this a secure way to login a user?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am new to web dev and especially razor.
I am tasked to build a web application.

I am trying to log in a user.

I did a html form which in short looks like this:

```
<table class="table-fullWitdh td-centered" style="width: 500px; margin-top: 100px;">
    <tr >
        <td class="rowHeight">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email*" name="emailaddress" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
        <td class="rowHeight">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password*" name="password" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
        <td class="rowHeight">
            <a href="#" id="mute">
                <p>Password vergessen?</p>
            </a>
        </td>              
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button class="baseButton" style="width: 50% !important; background-color: black !important;" onclick="CheckIfUserExists()">Login</button
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

eg:
[image]

This then is attached to some javascript code, which runs on the client:

```
 function CheckIfUserExists() {

        var email  = $("[name='emailaddress']").val();
        var password = $("[name='password']").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/Registration/2_Login/?handler=CheckIfUserExists",
            data: { "email": email, "password": password},
            headers:
            {
                "RequestVerificationToken": $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
            },
        }).done(function (data) {
            if(data == "notexisting") alert('User doesnt exist.')
            else location.href = "../MainMenu?id=" + data +"&handler=UserId"

        })
       .fail(function (error) {
           //nothing for now
       });
    }
```

It takes the input und makes an ajax call to my server which in return fires this function:

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostCheckIfUserExists(LogInData data)
        {
            // called from ajax           
            var user = await new RemoteUserService().GetItemByEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password);
            if(user == null) return NotFound();
            if (user.Count > 0)
            {
                IsLoggedIn = true;
                userId = user[0].Id.ToString();
                return new JsonResult(user[0].Id.ToString());
            }
            else return new JsonResult("notexisting");
         
        }
```

This basically calls our servers api and just checks if the user exists.
If so, I return a result from my ajax call as already seen here:

```
 }).done(function (data) {
                if(data == "notexisting") alert('User doenst exist.')
                else location.href = "../MainMenu?id=" + data +"&handler=UserId"
    
            })
```

... which then returns an info back to the user over whether he exists or not.

If he does, the I will redirect the user to the main menu.

So in short:

Frontend ajax call to the server, server checks backend, server returns results via ajax to the frontend, frontend does the redirect or the feedback (user doesnt exist).

I just want to understand if this is the right approach on things, or if I misunderstood something.

Just to clearify: All this code is working totally fine. Its just over if I understood it right.

Best,

J